# Export rows from dataframe which contain special characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in which some rows contains special characters, i want to extract all rows which contains special characters in all columns.

input:

```
**OWNERID   ACCOUNT ID              FIRST NAME  LAST NAME   MAILING COUNTRY**


3244323 gfdg9487589dffgjdskj    adc        FERRE        France

432245  $31sfjlkjdoi87098898f   assd       FERRE        France^

456546  578565545bfdgdf         asds       h            United Kingdom
```

expected output:

```
**OWNERID   ACCOUNT ID              FIRST NAME  LAST NAME   MAILING COUNTRY**

432245    $31sfjlkjdoi87098898f    assd         FERRE       France^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for select `object` columns (obviously strings) and test for punctation without spaces with regex in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for all filtered columns and then by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for get all rows if at least one match passed to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.select_dtypes('object').apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('[^\w\s]')).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   OWNERID             ACCOUNT ID FIRST NAME LAST NAME MAILING COUNTRY
1   432245  $31sfjlkjdoi87098898f       assd     FERRE         France^
```

Comment: Yeah, its working. i changed it to 'contains('[\^|\*|\$|\~|\#|\&]',regex=True)', its working as expected now.
Thank you, i really appreciate your quick response.